# SSH Like Port Forward But with authentication?

Tags: ssh

```
ssh user@server -R server:port1:localhost:port2
```

This way ssh will forward requests to server:port1 to localhost:port2, but anyone can connect to server:port1.

So I'm wondering of there's something that can do this but at the same time supports authentication?

Comment: what authentication? You can't simply do authentication on the TCP level.

Comment: @Jakuje so this is technically impossible?

Comment: If you state it this way, no. If you create the forwarding only on `localhost`, then you need co authenticate to the `server` using `ssh` and only then you can connect to the `localhost` port, if that would be enough.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Securing SSH port forwarding?](https://superuser.com/questions/1679106/securing-ssh-port-forwarding)

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do this using another ssh tunnel from your local machine.

First, you have to block external connections to **port1** of your server using iptables:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport port1 -i eth0 -j DROP
```

where eth0 is your WAN port.

Then create direct tunnel at port1 of your server from local port 5000 and this very step requires authentication

```
ssh -L user@server 5000:localhost:port1
```

Now you can connect to 5000 port of your local machine as if you connect to server:port1.