# Securing SSH port forwarding?

Tags: ssh, port-forwarding, authentication, tunnel, socks-proxy

I'd like to run a SOCKS server on a remote client (RC), that will receive requests (reverse-tunnel) from some cloud virtual server (VS), which will receive requests from my own local client (LC).

In other words,

1. VS redirects some local port A to local port B
2. LC connects to VS's port A (port A on VS is exposed to the internet)
3. RC reverse-tunnels to itself from VS port B

However, I'd like to ensure ultimately that all connections LC<->RC are authenticated & encrypted as well. In other words,

1. VS *only* accepts (and authenticates + encrypts) *SSH* connections from clients LC and RC. *No "unauthenticated" connections (nor even any "non-SSH" connections!) to VS ever get accepted (much less even forwarded to RC) at all -- they will all get dropped/ignored*. So, **only LC** can connect to VS port A, and **only RC** can connect to VS port B.
2. Thus, RC only accepts connections ultimately initiated by LC

Ideally, this would done by generating key-pairs on all devices and sharing all the public keys (over to all the devices). But, can SSH actually accomplish all of this? Does SSH reverse tunneling / port forwarding actually secure (authenticate & encrypt) all these connections, **even if** I'm only using it just for tunneling socks? (i.e., not creating any shells, or "terminals, or executing any remote commands at all, etc...)

*Edit: I don't need the socks server on RC to itself do any "socks authentication" (the RC socks server can just bind localhost, for that matter). For RC, I only need the `ssh -R` command (executed from RC) to ensure that whatever RC receives (and sends to its local socks server) it does so via an authenticated/encrypted connection to VS.

*Edit #2: Would it be possible to extend this to UDP connections as well? (e.g., for tunneling DNS requests as well)

Comment: SuperUsers QA format works best if you ask a single question per "question post", as someone might have the answer to one question, but not the other. Your question about UDP should be put in a new "question post".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Preliminary notes

- This answer is Unix-centric. `ssh` can be used in Windows. In Windows some concepts mentioned in this answer may not apply. Example commands use quoting and pathnames from the Unix world.
- I use OpenSSH. Other implementations may miss some features this answer uses.

---

#### About SSH tunnels

[This other answer](https://superuser.com/a/1679108/432690) is technically correct but it does not really address your problem. It's true the SSH protocol provides encryption and authentication. The client and the server authenticate to each other when the SSH connection starts. All data travelling through the connection is encrypted, including tunneled data; but…

Access to a tunnel is not restricted by SSH in any SSH-specific way. If the listening end is a TCP port then restrictions specific to networking will apply: interface (e.g. the local interface is not available from the outside), firewall etc. If the listening end is a Unix socket then restrictions specific to file access will apply (because the socket is a [file](https://superuser.com/a/1467109/432690)): mode, ownership, etc. (note: [manuals warn](https://man.openbsd.org/sshd_config#StreamLocalBindMask) that not all operating systems honor the file mode on Unix-domain socket files; still creating a socket in a directory with restricted access [should restrict access](https://superuser.com/a/1425631/432690) in any system).

If one can open the listening end then he or she can use the tunnel. There will be no prompt or anything injected by SSH. By design a tunnel created with `ssh -L` or `ssh -R` relays data from one end to the other (bidirectionally) as-is; it's meant to be transparent. This means when you connect to `some_address:port` there's no difference if the server is there on the machine with `some_address`, or it's behind one or more tunnels on a different machine; the server gets what you send and you get what the server sends.

If your RC uses `ssh -R` to tunnel the port B of VS to any `address:port` RC can access (in general `address:port` may or may not belong to RC) then connecting to port B of VS is like connecting to `address:port` from RC. If the listening port B of VS can be accessed from the Internet then anyone can reach `address:port` as if they were on RC. The transparency of the tunnel allows this. If the protocol being tunneled allows authentication, use it maybe. In general there may be no protocol, you may want to send an arbitrary stream, the tunnel will relay it as-is.

In your case maybe port B of VS cannot be reached from the Internet, but port A can and it is redirected to B. One way or another there is some exposed port that allows anyone connect to `address:port` as if they were on RC.

---

#### Improving security in general case

There are few methods of improving the setup and making it less open to the public:

- A firewall on VS may be configured to deny access to the exposed port from anywhere but LC. This requires LC to use a static IP address from which its communication gets to VS. If LC is behind NAT then VS will not be able to reliably tell apart LC from another host behind the same NAT. Setting firewall rules on VS requires administrative access to VS. You probably don't want to (or cannot) use this method.
- RC, when connecting with `ssh -R`, can make the SSH server on VS bind to the loopback interface of VS. Assuming the chosen port is 5555, it will be like `ssh -R 127.0.0.1:5555:address:port …`. Then VS should not redirect any exposed port to its end of the tunnel. To use the tunnel one needs to connect to `127.0.0.1:5555` ([or similar address](https://superuser.com/q/393700/432690)) from within VS.

  To connect from LC you need to find a way to reach `127.0.0.1:port` of VS as if you were on VS. This is simple, if only you have SSH access to VS. Use `ssh -L 127.0.0.1:7777:127.0.0.1:5555 …` on LC to tunnel port 7777 of LC to the right port on VS. Then on LC connect to `127.0.0.1:7777`. This connection will use the two chained tunnels and it will ultimately reach `address:port` from RC as if you were on RC.

  The method requires SSH access to VS from LC. Random guys from the Internet will not be able to use the tunnel. Users of LC will, if they connect to `127.0.0.1:7777`; this includes users other than you. On a private computer this is usually not a problem (see the notes section way below). However users of VS will be able to use the tunnel if they connect to `127.0.0.1:5555` inside VS. In a multi-user environment this may be a problem.
- To secure your tunnel from other users of VS, modify the previous method, so instead of using a TCP port on VS it uses a Unix socket. On RC you need to connect to VS with `ssh -R /path/to/socket:address:port …`; on LC you need to connect to VS with `ssh -L 7777:/path/to/socket …`. Use arbitrary `/path/to/` directory where the user (I mean the user RC connects as, i.e. the user RC specifies when `ssh`-ing to VS) can create files in VS. There are at least two problems:

  - `ssh -R` from RC will by default create the socket with such ownership and mode, so only the user RC connects as ([or VS's root](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/412234/108618)) can use it. In some systems the socket permissions are ignored ([restrict access to `/path/to/`](https://superuser.com/a/1425631/432690) then) but in Linux they work (see *Pathname socket ownership and permissions* in [`man 7 unix`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/unix.7.html)). This will secure your tunnel from other users of VS, what is exactly what we want. If LC connects to VS as the same user as RC then it's perfect. If from LC you act as another user on VS then the socket will have to be made available to you. RC will need to run `setfacl` in VS after creating the socket. This can be done by shell code supplied when RC does `ssh -R` (and the code should end with `exec sleep 2147483647` to prevent the connection from terminating, this number should be [safe and enough](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/660117/108618)).
  - If `/path/to/socket` already exists on VS then it must be removed before `ssh -R` can work. [An automatic solution exists](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/429903/108618), it requires `StreamLocalBindUnlink` to be `yes` on the server, in your case on VS. If you cannot configure VS this way then RC should `ssh … 'rm /path/to/socket'` first, before `ssh -R`. `StreamLocalBindUnlink` exists as an option for `ssh` but I think it applies to sockets created on the client side (we don't use such sockets here); [some say it's a bug](https://bugzilla.mindrot.org/show_bug.cgi?id=2601).

  Using sockets instead of TCP ports not only allows you to keep other users on VS away from your tunnel; it also prevents them from tricking you into using the wrong tunnel. Imagine RC uses `ssh -R` to create a tunnel only to find out the port it wants to use on VS is already taken. Some other user is using it, maybe as a tunnel. Maybe it leads to the same type of service you expect from RC. You don't know RC failed, you connect from LC as usual and send your data. From the point of view of the other user you are a random guy who uses their setup uninvited; or a victim who sends your sensitive data to them. This cannot happen if you use Unix sockets properly.

Note in the above cases you don't really need SSH access to RC. I mean whatever code RC should run, it can be set up once and automated by RC's administrator who may not be you. RC may not even run `sshd` (a server); `ssh` (client application) is enough for it. OTOH to chain the tunnels you need SSH access from LC to VS.

SSH access to RC gives you more options.

---

#### Specific case: tunneling SSH via SSH

I assume you cannot directly reach RC from LC (otherwise VS would not be needed in the first place). If it's the only thing that prevents you from `ssh`-ing from LC to RC, i.e. if an SSH server runs on RC and you have a key or a password to connect, then you can build tunnels in yet another way.

First you need to be able to access the SSH server of RC. This is easy: take the general case (elaborated above) of `address:port` and apply it for `127.0.0.1:22`.

Even if RC does `ssh -R '*:5555:127.0.0.1:22' …` and therefore requests VS to listen on all interfaces (including exposed ones) or if VS redirects some exposed port to the tunnel, the setup is quite secure. This is because anyone from the Internet who connects to the listening end of the tunnel will reach the SSH server of RC which requires authentication anyway.

I know tunneling SSH is not your goal. The point is now you can create any TCP tunnel you want between LC and RC by invoking `ssh` on LC. You can create many tunnels. E.g. to reach from LC some arbitrary `address:port` as if you were on RC, invoke on LC:

```
ssh -p 5555 -NL 127.0.0.1:1234:address:port userRC@VS
```

and on LC use `127.0.0.1:1234` in any program you want to connect to `address:port`.

Notes:

- The SSH connection that tunnels your data is itself tunneled between VS and RC. So it's a tunnel in a tunnel.
- `userRC@VS` means you need to use the address of VS but the username (and credentials) for RC. We're using the address of VS only because it's the listening end of the tunnel that leads to RC. You don't need SSH access to VS.
- It may happen RC cannot create its tunnel because somebody else has taken the chosen port on VS. We noted this possibility for the general case, it was insecure. Now it's not that bad. If this happens and you (from LC) try to connect to what you think is the SSH server of RC, [you will be able to tell it's not RC](https://superuser.com/a/1657396/432690), if only you're paying attention to fingerprints. `ssh` with its `known_hosts` file will try to help, although it [may not tell apart `VS:22` from `VS:5555`](https://serverfault.com/q/141553), so you may get false warnings. Anyway *in principle* you will be able to tell.

  This means a "hijacker" cannot trick you if you're careful. Still he or she can prevent you from reaching RC. The method using Unix sockets to create chained tunnels will come handy (note it requires SSH access from LC to VS). Again, take the general case (elaborated above) of `address:port` and apply it for `127.0.0.1:22`. The method involves `ssh -R` on RC and `ssh -L` on LC. Then you are able to reach the SSH server of RC by connecting to `127.0.0.1:7777` on LC. Finally an additional `ssh` command on LC in a form of:

  ```
  ssh -p 7777 -NL 127.0.0.1:1234:address:port userRC@127.0.0.1
  ```

  will allow you to create a tunnel to `address:port` (seen from RC) locally available as `127.0.0.1:1234`. It will be a tunnel in the chained tunnels.

---

#### Specific case: SOCKS

You wrote:

> I'd like to run a SOCKS server on a remote client (RC) […]

If a SOCKS server can be reached via `address:port` from RC then to connect from LC you can use any of the above methods that are not specific to SOCKS.

However if you can access the SSH server of RC from LC then you don't need a standalone SOCKS server. There is `ssh -D`, it's somewhat similar to `ssh -L`, it listens on a local port. Instead of forwarding the port to some arbitrary `address:port` on the remote side, `ssh -D` creates a SOCKS server for you, as if the port was tunneled to some SOCKS server running beside the SSH server on the remote machine. It's a built-in SOCKS server to use with `ssh`.

To use it as if a standalone SOCKS server was running on RC, you need SSH access to RC. That's why the previous section of this answer concentrated on reaching the SSH server of RC from LC first.

If you could reach RC directly (without VS), you would use `ssh -D` on LC this way:

```
ssh -ND 127.0.0.1:8888 userRC@RC
```

and you would configure your browser (or whatever) to use `127.0.0.1:8888` as the SOCKS proxy. With tunneling via VS the situation is like in the previous section, except you want `-D 127.0.0.1:8888` instead of `-L 127.0.0.1:1234:address:port`. Example:

```
ssh -p 5555 -ND 127.0.0.1:8888 userRC@VS
```

In general this is what I would do if I were you. I would set up SSH access from LC to RC, then I would use `ssh -D` on LC.

Less known is the fact `ssh -R` can act as SOCKS proxy. If the tunnel RC creates was built without specifying `address:port`, i.e. if the command was like `ssh -R 127.0.0.1:5555 …`, then you could use `127.0.0.1:5555` of VS to reach SOCKS proxy running on RC (as if a standalone SOCKS proxy was on `address:port` there and the tunnel lead to it). So an administrator of RC can give you SOCKS proxy without running a standalone SOCKS server or even an SSH server, `ssh` is enough. From LC you would use it like in the general case. The difference is `ssh -R` acting as SOCKS proxy cannot bind to a Unix socket (at least not at the time I'm writing this), it has to be a TCP port. Firmly restricting access by using a Unix socket instead is therefore impossible.

---

#### Notes

- `ssh` and `sshd` are highly configurable. There are many options (see [`man 5 ssh_config`](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh_config) and [`man 5 sshd_config`](https://man.openbsd.org/sshd_config)). The same simple `ssh` command may work differently depending on options in the files. E.g. when I say "`ssh -R` from RC will by default create the socket with ownership and mode so only the user RC connects as […] can use it", do not read "by default" as "when there are no further options to `ssh` in the command line". The relevant option is `StreamLocalBindMask` on the server (in `sshd_config`), I think, if it's specified then "by default" does not apply. There are more options that can interfere with what you want to do, e.g. [`AllowTcpForwarding`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/58756/108618).
- Creating a SOCKS proxy with `ssh` is explained in this answer of mine: [*How to create a SOCKS proxy with ssh?*](https://superuser.com/a/1308648/432690) In the context of the linked answer your LC is `A` and `B` (`A`=`B` case), your RC is `C`. Your VS sits between `B` and `C`, the linked answer does not consider such node. Once you move VS out of the problem by making `ssh` from LC to RC possible, the linked answer can be useful.
- Even the most secure setup we considered in this answer allows other users of LC to use the ultimate tunnel. If this is a problem and if the program that is going to use the tunnel can use a Unix socket instead of a port, consider a socket in LC. If the program must use a TCP port, I guess a separate network namespace can help; but setting it up is not trivial, I won't elaborate. If you want security without excessive effort, being a sole user of LC helps.
- Being a sole user of VS also helps. After all I wrote it should be clear why it is so.

---

#### UDP

> Would it be possible to extend this to UDP connections as well?

When you can reach RC from LC via `ssh`, you can create more than one tunnel. But not UDP, not as easily. There is no support ([why?](https://superuser.com/q/1068476/432690)). Tricks that read UDP, write to TCP, tunnel TCP and "translate" back to UDP ([example](https://superuser.com/a/53109/432690)) are flawed, do not trust them. [UDP preserves message boundaries, TCP does not](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9563694/10765659), this is where the flaw comes from. [This answer mentioning `ssh -w`](https://superuser.com/a/53149/432690) seems good (at least not flawed in theory) but I haven't tested. A full-scale VPN to which you connect using a TCP tunnel is a possibility, although it may be slow.

Answer (score 1):

SSH provides encryption for everything that uses a *channel*, in which the SOCKS functionality (as well as shell, port forwarding or SFTP) is wrapped. An SSH connection is made up of layers, which all have a specific function in the overall protocol. A simplified view for this example:

- The transport layer ([RFC 4253](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4253)) provides encryption
- The user authentication layer ([RFC 4252](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4252)) provides authentication, through various means
- The connection layer ([RFC 4254](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4254)) provides the above mentioned *channels*.

Comment: Thank you! But does that mean the VS in my example can ignore all non-SSH connections, for that matter? So then, it's not like just *any* random programs on the internet can send anything to RC. This is just to prevent RC from being a socks server for just "anyone" on the internet...

Comment: Indeed, it's actually fairly common to "hide" internal services behind SSH (or VPN) connections.

Comment: However, according to https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-setup-ssh-socks-tunnel-for-private-browsing/ , it seems ssh port proxying some port A to B (like I will be doing on VS) means ssh on VS will accept "any random program" connecting to port A. For example, it seems browsers like Chrome/Firefox do not need to authenticate themselves before the ssh port-forwarder at all. I'm looking for a way for ssh port-forwarding to only accept connections from trusted sources (sources who's public ssh keys are trusted by VS). In other words, "Don't port-forward *just anybody* who arrives at port A!"

Comment: Basically, I want to make sure SSH only ever port-forwards connections from *authenticated clients*. So, *non-authenticated clients* never get anything even port-forwarded at all! (In other words, the port-forwarder **itself** is the "gatekeeper" !!)